# get timestamp of all files listed within text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to get the timestamps of all of the files within a text file.
Files listed in text file:

```
folder/file1
folder/file2
```

System should output timestamp of:

```
folder/file1 timestamp-of-file
folder/file2 timestamp-of-file
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
f = open('config.dat','r')
list_contents = f.read().split('\n')
timestamp=os.path.getmtime(list_contents)
for a in timestamp:
    print(timestamp)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Can you give example of expected output ?

Comment: anyway really.  I just want the system to read the text file and take those text entries and check timestamps of each file list in text file.

Comment: Apart from the incorrect indentation of `f.close()` what's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
f = open('config.dat','r')
list_contents = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()
for a in list_contents:
    print(a, os.path.getmtime(a))
```

`os.path.getmtime(path)` returns the timestamp of the file to be found under `path`, so you have to pass each of the entries of `list_contents` separately to this function.

Comment: Ahh brilliant... This is doing the job... It outputs this as expect however returning errors on 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: This is probably due to what your 'config.dat' looks like, because there might be empty lines in there (e.g. the last line) that do not correspond to paths, of course.

Comment: perfect.  Thanks for the help... Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the entire file into memory is unnecessary and potentially wasteful.

```
with open(config.dat) as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
         filename = line.rstrip('\n')
         print(filename, os.path.getmtime(filename))
```

The `getmtime()` return value is a Unix timestamp; you might want to pass it to `time.strftime('%c', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(filename))` for human-readable output.